# CSS3 Transform to reveal lower layer

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-transforms

I'm learning to use CSS3 Transforms. I've created the demo below that reveals a portion of the layer beneath the visible layer.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uFHpe

On hovering over over the revealed layer, I would like it to remain visible but at the moment it causes the revealed layer to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try appliying it when `over` is hovered and when `background` is hovered using the sibling selector `~`

```
.over:hover, .background:hover ~ .over {
   transform: translateX(-200px);
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

For more information on CSS selectors, [this is a great and informative article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/)